# Python, sending command to GPIB instrument

Tags: python, string-formatting, gpib

I need to send a command to a GPIB instrument and I can do it like this: `power.write("volt 0.01")`.
This command sets the output of my power source to 0.01V, however, I'm trying to take an I-V curve and want to set the source to different values and take a measurement at each value. I basically need some sort of loop to do this for me.  I tried the following:

```
k=0
while k<= 1:
    power.write("volt k")
    k=k+0.01
```

This doesn't work because k gets send as `'k'`, not as a number. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `power.write("volt k")`, use:

```
power.write("volt " + str(k))
                 ^
          observe space here!
```

If you want to control the output precision, you can use the following:

```
power.write("volt %0.2f" % k)
```

That is, if `k` is `4.85866` then using `%0.2f` means `volt 4.86` is sent to the device. If using `%0.4f` then `volt 4.8587` is sent to the device. Note the rounding!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `power.write("volt k")`, use:

```
power.write("volt %0.2f" % k)
```